# A counterexample for a result of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence. Define another sequence $(a^*_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ by

$$
a^*_n=\frac{a_n+a_{n+1}}{2}. 
$$
Give an counterexample to show that 'if $a^*_n\to\infty$, then $a_n\to\infty$' is false.

I got stuck at this question. I know this should be incorrect but I just can't find a counterexample. Could somebody help me with this? Thanks very much.

Comment: Make the $a_n$ with $n$ odd all $0$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks very much! I knew the example would be simple but I just didn't come up with this idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sequence:

$a_n=\begin{cases}
n & n\text{ odd} \\
0 &n\text{ even} \\
\end{cases}$

Can you see how $a_n^*\rightarrow\infty$ but $a_n$ does not (nor does it converge to any value)?

Comment: Yep I can see that $1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2},\dots$ which is a unbounded increasing sequence..

Comment: Yep, and importantly because every second term is 0, you can't say that $a_n\rightarrow\infty$

Answer (score 0):

Define the sequence $a_n=n(1+(-1)^n)$ then $a_n \not \to \infty$ but $a_n^\star\to \infty$.